# Hack Concerns As Installed And Ran Python Tool Shutdown Computer

Tags: python

A friend has an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. He likes to pentest and today downloaded a python tool from GitHub. He installed via 'git clone' and then ran it via terminal. Entered (purely for academic testing) a 'target' added other details and hit 'run'. Then to his surprise the terminal posted a message saying 'LOL stop ddosing' his laptop and screen then powered down.

Now he's worried there might be some malware/RAT on his laptop. He removed via the trash bin the program and swiftly changed his Ubuntu root password. Is there any other precautions he could take, apart from not running unknown tools from GitHub? Any advice or help would be very welcome.

Comment: If he thinks he's been infected he should erase his system and clean it fresh.  And then, only run pentesting tools inside a VM that's isolated, or run from a LiveUSB for pentesting only.  There is ***no advantage*** and ***infinite risk*** running pentest tools, etc. from your 'normal use' system and you should isolate things where you can in VMs, containers, etc.

Comment: Thomas , thanks for your comments and advice, I told him he may need to format, but he's trying if possible to avoid that.